# How to pass the value of a variable into a mysql foreach row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * From orders");

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
 {
     $datef = strtotime($row['Date1']);
     $dates = strtotime($row['Date2']);
     $rprice = $row['Pprice'];

     $datediff = floor(($datef + $dates ) / 86400);
     $total = $datediff * $rprice;

     echo $total; 
 }
```

After that code, i want to update a table and insert into a colum the price **for each of the rows**. as far as i echo `$total` i get back just 1 row...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: You're missing the closing quote on your query, is that just a typo?

Comment: This question is strange

Comment: yes sorry i will fix it

Comment: Can you explain a bit more

Comment: After the while loop? What's the [name|structure] of the table you want to modify? What is anything? This question makes my brain hurt.

Comment: the result of the query gives me back more than one rows, the problem is when i echo $total i get back just 1 row. What i want to do is to get the $total for each row and insert that value into the table for each row of the previous query

Comment: That still doesn't seem like enough information. What have **you** tried in order to make this work for you?

Comment: try this `echo $total.'<br />';` maybe you got many result near of eachother

Comment: just an insert into query inside 'while loop' to put the $total, but the result is the same in all the rows

Answer (score 1):

try this if it works

```
  function total($date1,$date2,$price){

  $datedif = floor(($date1 + $date2 ) / 86400);
 $total = $datedif * $price ;
  return $total ;

 }
 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * From orders");

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 

{   $datef = strtotime($row['Date1']);
    $dates = strtotime($row['Date2']);
    $rprice=$row['Pprice'];
    echo total($datef,$dates,$rprice).'<br />' ;

 }
```

EDIT:

```
insert into ammounts (Total_Cost) VALUES ('total($datef,$dates,$rprice)')
WHERE id = '$row["id"]'
```

Comment: nope, i just get back the 2 dates and again 1 row for the price

Comment: Nice as far its ok, now i want to insert tha price into a column

Comment: what i should put into WHERE statement? Thank you very much

Comment: what price ? $total? what you want in where statment ?

Comment: yes the $total, i want to insert it into a culumn Total_Cost in a table called ammounts

Comment: you mean this ? you want insert it in the same time where you count them ?

Comment: hey thank you again, something is wrong cause the column total_cost takes 0 as values :(

Comment: 1- make the insert statment in while loop , 2-make sure you have id in your table as i done.

Comment: i have try it, it gives me '0' :(

Comment: i dont know what your tables are and your code , but since this question is solved you can post the other question with full code.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have `order_id` coulmn as PRIMARY KEY and `total` column in your `orders` table.

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 

{   $datef = strtotime($row['Date1']);
    $dates = strtotime($row['Date2']);
    $rprice=$row['Pprice'];
    $total=total($datef,$dates,$rprice);
    $query=mysql_query("UPDATE orders SET total = $total WHERE order_id = '$row[order_id]'") or die(mysql_error());
    echo $total.'<br />' ;
 }
```